# How to connect to redis in Django?

Tags: python, django, redis

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to connect to redis to save my object in it, but it gives me this error when i try to connect

> Error 10061 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it

How does it work, what should i give in location and i am on a proxy from my company. Need some detailed explanation on location.

Comment: Are you running redis on your local machine at that address? How did you start it?

Comment: Yes I am on local machine.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Is redis running on that local machine?

Comment: nope. it does not. How do i run it. ? or can i connect to redis server directly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if your redis is password protected, you should have a config like this:

```
CACHES.update({
    "redis": {
        "BACKEND": "redis_cache.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1",
        "OPTIONS": {
             "PASSWORD": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
             "CLIENT_CLASS": "redis_cache.client.DefaultClient",
        },
    },
})
```

Answer (score 3):

First start the redis server. Your OS will provide a mechanism to do that, e.g. on some Linuxes you could use `systemctl start redis`, or `/etc/init.d/redis start` or similar. Or you could just start it directly with:

```
$ redis-server
```

which will run it as a foreground process.

Then try running the `redis-cli ping` command. Receiving a `PONG` response indicates that redis is in fact up and running on your local machine:

```
$ redis-cli ping
PONG
```

Once you have that working try Django again.

Comment: I downloaded redis server but now it says  "Client sent AUTH, but no password is set". I have redis-cli.exe open but i cannot find a command to setpassword for the server. need help on this

Comment: @Yogi: You don't seem to have configured a password in `django-redis`, however, have you tried reading the Redis [documentation](http://redis.io/commands/auth)? You can use the `requirepass` config setting to set a password for the server. Make sure that they match.

Comment: Also check https://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/#_configure_as_cache_backend . A password is configured in the location URL.